# /etc/sudoer/ - Is it possible to enter into single user mode through putty?

Tags: linux, centos, putty

I accidentally chown the /etc/sudoer/ folder so that my sudo command no longer works. (I can only ssh into this Linux Centos vm on windows azure) 
I don't have the root password and I wonder how I may reset the root password, or just chown the /etc/ folder back to root. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe their tech support can help you?

Answer (score 0):

My only idea would be trying to crack the system, through privilege-scalation.

Perhaps there's an unpatched vulnerability in the system you can exploit easily.